# Angular, hot to show or hide elements depending on # bookmark in url

Tags: javascript, html, angular, single-page-application

I have a html page with several sections. In the main section I have links to the others, made like this: `<a href="#sec1"></a>` and in every section a `<a href="#"></a>` to get back to the main section. I want Angular to detect chages on page bookmark and to show and hide the right section depending on it. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

```
// given URL http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo#hashValue
var hash = $location.hash();
// => "hashValue"
```

Add this to your controller and based on that hash value you can show or hide your element.

Comment: It works, also added a `$watch` on `$location.hash()` to detect its changes